# How to setup a new Test environment in azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-group

I have existing DEV, QA and Prod environment. for each environment, a resource group attached. We have Storage Accounts, Application Insights, SQL Server, Data Factories, Virtual Network, APP Service, Public IP Address, Logic App, Function App and Key Vaults and SENDGRID API

So If I want to create a new testing environment which is the replica of DEV, do we need to create/ copy DEV Resource Group and all the content. Is it enough
What is the best possible solution.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to create Azure Resource Manager templates for your complete environment. This way, you can script the creation of your environment and create environments at will. Azure DevOps supports deploying ARM templates and by parameterizing things like resource names you can easily create multiple environments from your pipelines.

Since you already have a working environment on Azure, the easiest way is to export that environment to Azure. See [Quickstart: Create and deploy Azure Resource Manager templates by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-quickstart-create-templates-use-the-portal) on how to do this. Be aware that the exported template will be very large since it also includes default values that you would normally skip when creating the template. You still need to do some tweaking and make sure that you parameterize everything you want to change between the deployments of your environment.